# Grinding feeling when pushing Clutch 1/4 way - VW Polo SE 2018 Manual

Tags: vw, clutch, manual-transmission

I have a Manual 2018 Polo SE.

Recently I have had a minor issue, sometimes when I am in first gear and I push the clutch down a quarter slowly or release it to 3 quarters slowly, I can feel what can only be described as a rough "grinding" and can hear it quietly.

If I hold the pedal in the 1/4 position it only lasts a second or so when moving, meaning it is not constant when holding the pedal in this position.

Is this a certain part of the clutch that is worn and causing this jarring feeling? I haven't had any warning lights, or haven't noticed anything else at any other speeds.

Comment: Does it go away once the car is warmed up?

Comment: @SteveMatthews No - sometimes it happens at the start of a journey and sometimes the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it doesn't go away once the car is warmed up, I'd suggest that it's most likely the clutch release bearing has some wear.  In most cases this is nothing more than an annoyance and can safely be left but ought to be monitored.  If it gets significantly nosier, it will need to be investigated which unfortunately will likely mean removal of the gearbox and bellhousing from the engine which is a fairly major undertaking.

Comment: Thanks Steve, just out of curiosity, if it had been affected by the car warming up what would you think it was instead?

Comment: I'd think it was something like either gearbox oil or a worn syncromesh ring on first gear.